# How to remove list of elements from a Tensorflow tensor

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

For the following tensor:

```
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 10, 6), dtype=int64, numpy=
 array([[[  3,  16,  43,  10,   7, 431],
         [  3,   2,   6,   5,   7,   2],
         [  3,  37,   5,   7,   2,  12],
         [  3,   2,  11,   5,   7,   2],
         [  3,   2,   6,  18,  14, 195],
         [  3,   2,   6,   5,   7, 195],
         [  3,   2,   6,   5,   7,   9],
         [  3,   2,  11,   7,   2,  12],
         [  3,  16,  52,  92, 177, 923],
         [  3,   9,  43,  10,   7,   9]],
 
        [[  3,   2,  22, 495, 230,   4],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5, 102, 122],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5, 102, 230],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 908],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 450],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 122],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 122],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 230],
         [  3,   2,  22,  70,  34, 470],
         [  3,   2,  22, 855, 450,   4]]], dtype=int64)>)
```

I want to remove the last list `[  3,   2,  22, 855, 450,   4]` in the tensor. I tried with `tf.unstack` but it didn't work.

Comment: are the indices known to you?

Comment: @  AloneTogether, no . I need to remove any list, but only one list

Comment: You want to create a ragged tensor?. The first with 10 rows and the second with 9 rows?

Comment: @ V.M, yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also simply use `tf.ragged.boolean_mask` to exclude the row you do not want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[[  3,  16,  43,  10,   7, 431],
         [  3,   2,   6,   5,   7,   2],
         [  3,  37,   5,   7,   2,  12],
         [  3,   2,  11,   5,   7,   2],
         [  3,   2,   6,  18,  14, 195],
         [  3,   2,   6,   5,   7, 195],
         [  3,   2,   6,   5,   7,   9],
         [  3,   2,  11,   7,   2,  12],
         [  3,  16,  52,  92, 177, 923],
         [  3,   9,  43,  10,   7,   9]],
 
        [[  3,   2,  22, 495, 230,   4],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5, 102, 122],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5, 102, 230],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 908],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 450],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 122],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 122],
         [  3,   2,  22,   5,  70, 230],
         [  3,   2,  22,  70,  34, 470],
         [  3,   2,  22, 855, 450,   4]]])
x_shape = tf.shape(x)
remove = tf.constant([3, 2, 22, 855, 450, 4])

mask = tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x, remove), axis=-1)
x = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(x, ~mask)
print(x)
```

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[3, 16, 43, 10, 7, 431],
  [3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 2],
  [3, 37, 5, 7, 2, 12],
  [3, 2, 11, 5, 7, 2],
  [3, 2, 6, 18, 14, 195],
  [3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 195],
  [3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 9],
  [3, 2, 11, 7, 2, 12],
  [3, 16, 52, 92, 177, 923],
  [3, 9, 43, 10, 7, 9]]     , [[3, 2, 22, 495, 230, 4],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 102, 122],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 102, 230],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 70, 908],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 70, 450],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 70, 122],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 70, 122],
                               [3, 2, 22, 5, 70, 230],
                               [3, 2, 22, 70, 34, 470]]]>
```

Comment: you can simplify the mask, `tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x, remove), axis=-1)`

Comment: True, broadcasting works here. Thanks! Will update!

Answer (score 0):

you can try below to remove the last list from the tensor:

```
sliced_tensor = tf.slice(tensor, [0, 0, 0], [2, 9, 6])
```

Comment: @-apan,thank you, but this way remove two lists: [  3   9  43  10   7   9] and [  3   2   22  855  450   4], the last list in each matrix. I need to remove only one list

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
new_tensor = tf.slice(tensor, [0,0,0], [2,9,6], [1,1,1])
```

Comment: @ apan, same problem!

Comment: Why not just update your other answer?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?